# Python django Usermodel extending to custom user model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

The problem is i need an extra field to add my Django usermodel via a custom user model
called  'is_admin'

so ,this is the code i added to model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

but i registered this model to admin.py

when i tried to add a user using django admin page the password stores as plain not hashing hos to solve this problem

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'cAdmin.CustomUser'
```

i've already changed the default user model

and

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser,Priority
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
admin.site.register(Priority)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ModelAdmin` will by default use a *vanilla* `ModelForm`, and that will indeed not hash the password.

We can however easily work with a `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm` which will then use `.set_password` instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm


@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
```

Indeed, if we look at the source code of the [**`BaseUserCreationForm`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/07b7a3ab7573a0685975602c437ce4795a8885e7/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L139-L146), we see:

> ```
> def save(self, commit=True):
>     user = super().save(commit=False)
>     user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
>     if commit:
>         user.save()
>         if hasattr(self, "save_m2m"):
>             self.save_m2m()
>     return user
> ```